# Why can we make a recursive definition?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Background: ZFC in classical first-order logic.

To make a definition, we first need to proof *something* does exist. So, this question is actually about proving *something* exists based on a recursion.

I know that when you want to prove the existence of a certain function with the domain of ordinal numbers, you can use the transfinite recursion theorem. But our *things* are not always a function of this sort. For example, when we define the truth value function on the set of formulas in predicate logic, we usually define it recursively based on *the number of the logical symbols in a formula*(or *complexity*). But for a certain complexity of the formulae, there're many cases to deal with. I can't figure out how to prove such a definition does make sense, aka the function does exist.

Comment: Rather than say "we usually define it recursively..." can you please give a specific example of a definition that you are having difficulty with.

Comment: @RobArthan [This](http://www.davidagler.com/teaching/logic/handouts/slides/Slide9_PredicateLogic_VariableAssignments.pdf), see "Definition (RL-valuation using names)".

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a recursive definition produces a value for every natural number appearing as the index is a consequence of the induction axiom, which is part of Peano Arithmetic (PA).  This is not quite enough to get the existence of the function as a single object.  The latter follows from the axiom of separation of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF).  Thus, PA gives you the value at any $n$, and ZF guarantees the existence of the function as a single entity (no "C" is needed).

Comment: How do you use the axiom of separation to get that single function?

Comment: The axiom enables one to pass from a predicate to a set; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification (of course, a function is viewed as a set via its graph).

Comment: What should be the *big* set in the axiom?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly, but perhaps this will help: if you have $\phi(n)$ assigned for each $n\in\mathbb N$ then you can consider the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ satisfying $y=\phi(x)$.  The set exists by separation.

Comment: What is that *ϕ(n)*? I mean, what does it say intuitively? It seems it is already the function, the existence of which we need to prove. I don't think we can have this ϕ by the induction axiom.

Comment: Actually I see I misread your question as being more elementary than it is.  I now see that you are interested in *infinite* ordinal numbers and *transfinite* recursion.  This is indeed equivalent to set-theoretic principles but I would leave this to people who are more expert than I am in the subject.  If you like I can delete my *answer* so it does not look like your *question* has been answered already.

Comment: At wiki it says: "Transfinite induction is an extension of mathematical induction to well-ordered sets, for example to sets of ordinal numbers or cardinal numbers. Its correctness is a theorem of ZFC."  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction

Comment: Doesn't your method work? Anyway, I think what we get from the induction axiom is, the $\phi (x)$ in [this expression of the axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#:~:text=the%20first%2Dorder%20induction%20axiom%20for%20%CF%86%20is%20the%20sentence) is some formula that means there's a truth value function for formulae with a complexity of no more than x. Then, I don't know how to proceed. (to be continued)

Comment: My intuitive thought is, since we have the existence of functions for each natural numbers, $F_1, F_2, F_3$ and so on, maybe we can just take the union of them all, that is $F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3 \cup ...$. But I'm not sure if that can be carried out in first-order ZFC.

Comment: Well for natural numbers there is no difficulty, as I outlined, and can be done in ZF.  For infinite ordinals, ZF may not be enough; there is some discussion of this at the wiki page.

Comment: What does the '$ϕ$' mean in your outline?

Comment: Let's stick to finite $n$ for the time being.  I thought what you meant to ask the following.  Given that $\phi$ is defined recursively by some relation expressing $\phi(n+1)$ in terms of $\phi(n)$, how do we know that there exists such a $\phi$ at all $n$?  That's how I interpreted your question originally (and that's what the title of your *question* suggests).

Comment: How/why can you write '$ϕ(n)$' in your outline? We only proved functions '$F_1,F_2,F_3...$' exist, not '$ϕ(n)$' itself, so we can't use '$ϕ(n)$' in {$(x, y) \in \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N} : y=ϕ(x) $}.

Comment: If what's bothering you is taking countable unions of sets, there is certainly no problem doing so in ZFC, especially if their ranks (say, von Neumann rank) are uniformly bounded.

Comment: @MikhailKatz This answer isn't quite right - the key axiom is **replacement**, not separation (think about $n\mapsto\aleph_n$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, let's make a deal: I delete my answer, and you post yours.  A deal?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing a reference to the kind of definition you are having problems. Let me see if I can give a simpler example that may help you.

Let's look at the set of formulas in the $(\lnot, \land)$ fragment of propositional logic over a set $V_1, V_2, \ldots$ of propositional variables. It may be defined as the smallest set of strings of symbols that satisfies the following rules

- Any $V_i$ is a formula;
- If $\alpha$ is a formula then so is $(\lnot \alpha)$;
- If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are formulas  then so is $(\alpha \land \beta)$.

By somewhat tedious induction that shows along the way that for any left bracket in a formula there is a unique right bracket that matches it in the appropriate sense, you can show that for any formula $\alpha$, either $\alpha$ is $V_i$ for some $i$, or there is a unique formula $\beta$ such that $\alpha$ is $(\lnot \beta)$, or there are unique formulas $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha$ is $(\beta \land \gamma)$ (and these three possibilities are mutually exclusive). Let's call this the "structure theorem".

Now let's define a function $D$ that measures the depth of a formula. We want it to satisfy the following definition scheme:

- $D(V_i) = 1$
- $D((\lnot \alpha)) = 1 + D(\alpha)$
- $S((\lnot \alpha \land \lnot \beta)) = 1 + \max(D(\alpha), D(\beta))$

We have to prove that such a $D$ exists. To do this we show that there exists a unique chain of partial functions $D_1 \subseteq D_2 \subseteq D_3 \subseteq \ldots$ such that $D_i$ is defined for all formulas containing at most $i$ symbols and such that each $D_i$ satisfies the definition scheme above for all formulas in its domain. We can then take $D$ to be the union of the $D_i$. To prove the $D_i$ exist, we show by induction on $n$ that for every $n$, given a chain of functions $D_1 \subseteq D_2 \subseteq D_{n-1}$ satisfying our requirements on the $D_i$, there is a unique $D_n$ such that $D_{n-1} \subseteq D_n$ that also satisfies our requirements.

The proof goes like this. Assume given a chain $D_1 \subseteq D_2 \subseteq \ldots D_{n-1}$ satisfying our requirements. Define $D_n$ so that $D_n(\alpha) = D_{n-1}(\alpha)$ for any formula with less than $n$ symbols. If $\alpha$ has $n$ symbols, then by the structure theorem, exactly one of the following applies:

- $\alpha$ is $V_i$ for some $i$, so that $n = 1$, the given chain is empty and we may (and must) take $D_n(\alpha) = 1$;
- $\alpha$ is $(\lnot \beta)$ for some unique $\beta$, which clearly has less than $n$ symbols. We may (and must) take $D_n(\alpha) = 1 + D_{n-1}(\beta)$;
- $\alpha$ is $(\beta \land \gamma)$ for some unique $\beta$ and $\gamma$, which clearly both have less than $n$ symbols. We may (and must) take $D_n(\alpha) = 1 + \max(D_{n-1}(\beta), D_{n-1}(\gamma))$.

Thus we have found the unique extension of our chain of $n-1$ functions to a chain of $n$ functions.

The reference you give is being a little bit casual about the need for brackets in the formal representation of a formula to ensure that parsing is unique (that's what the structure theorem says). This is a standard slight abuse of notation. You also don't need to go through all the details of the course-of-values induction every time. Instead, you just recognise that you can uniquely define a function by giving its value on the atomic formulas (the $V_i$) and its value on a compound formula ($(\lnot \alpha)$ or $(\alpha \land \beta)$) as a function of its values on the immediate subformulas of the formula. This is often referred to as definition by recursion over the structure of the formula.